# Electron app doesnt launch after modefing app.asar on macOS

Tags: javascript, html, macos, electron, asar

So l am trying to modify an electron application. Firstly, I extracted app.asar into a folder then modefed an html file and launched the program. And it worked, my html was applyed to this application. Later then I tried to make the same thing on macOS and when I extracted app.asar folder, it stop working. I edited everything in package folder of application.

Somehow app detecting changes on mac but not on windows. I thought it detects it by editing date and then I tried to change date to old and it still won't work.